# Is there a way to solve $\alpha_1\sin{(x})+\beta_1\cos{(x)}+\alpha_2\sin{(2x)}+\beta_2\cos{(2x)}=c$ for $x$?

Tags: trigonometry

> Is there any method to solve the equation above for $x$?
>
> $$\alpha_1\sin{(x})+\beta_1\cos{(x)}+\alpha_2\sin{(2x)}+\beta_2\cos{(2x)}=c$$

This would be a trivial problem if it was *only* the first pair or second pair of functions. Perhaps it's also a trivial question as it stands and I'm simply unaware. All I know is that WolframAlpha was really chugging and couldn't give a clean answer before timing out.

Comment: Defining $t:=\tan(x/2)$, you can expand the expression and substitute $$\sin x\to\frac{2t}{1+t^2} \qquad \cos x \to \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ (This is known as the ["tangent half-angle substitution"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula#The_tangent_half-angle_substitution_in_integral_calculus) or the ["Weierstrass substitution"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution).) This converts the eqn into a quartic polynomial eqn in $t$. While there is a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) for the roots, it isn't pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the double-angle formulas $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$ and $\sin(2x) = 2 \cos(x) \sin(x)$, so your equation becomes:

$$\alpha_1 \sin(x) + \beta_1 \cos(x) + \alpha_2 (\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)) + 2\beta_2 \cos(x) \sin(x) = c$$

For the sake of brevity, let $k = \cos(x)$ and $s = \sin(x)$.

$$\alpha_1 s + \beta_1 k + \alpha_2 (k^2 - s^2) + 2\beta_2 k s = c$$

But $k^2 + s^2 = 1$, so $k^2 = 1 - s^2$.

$$\alpha_1 s + \beta_1 k + \alpha_2 (1 - 2s^2) + 2\beta_2 k s = c$$

Solving for $k$ gives:

$$k = \frac{c - \alpha_1 s - \alpha_2 + 2 \alpha_2 s^2}{\beta_1 + 2\beta_2 s}$$

Squaring both sides gives:

$$k^2 = 1 - s^2 = \frac{(c - \alpha_1 s - \alpha_2 + 2 \alpha_2 s^2)^2}{(\beta_1 + 2\beta_2 s)^2}$$

which, after a bunch of algebra (that I'm not 100% sure I did correctly), expands to a [quartic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation) in terms of $s$.

$$-4(\alpha_2^2 + \beta_2^2)s^4 + 4 \alpha_1 \alpha_2 s^3 + (4  - 4 \alpha_2 c - \alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2 + 4 \beta^2 - \beta_1^2 - 4 \beta_1 \beta_2 )s^2 + (2 \alpha_1 c - 2 \alpha_1 \alpha_2)s + (\beta_1^2 + 4 \beta_1 \beta_2 + 2\alpha_2 c  - \alpha_2^2 - c^2) = 0$$

From here, it's “just” a matter of plugging the coefficients into the Quartic Formula to solve for $s$, and then taking the inverse sine of that to get $x$.

Fortunately, you didn't ask *what* the solutions were, just “is there a way to solve” your equation.  And since quartic polynomials (unlike quintic and higher) have “closed-form” solutions, the answer is **yes** :-)